# UNIX - Adding header to the first column of every line

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a question about processing files in UNIX line by line. What I have right now is this -

Source file:

```
header-1 header-sub1
field1|field2|field3|field4
field5|field6|field7|field8
header-2
field9|field0|fieldA|fieldB
```

Now I want to process this file line by line and generate an output file. The header should be appended to the first column of every line until the next header is found. That is in essence the output file should be as below:

Output:

```
header-1 header-sub1|field1|field2|field3|field4
header-1 header-sub1|field5|field6|field7|field8
header-2|field9|field0|fieldA|fieldB
```

The shell script loop that I have with me is this -

```
while read line 
do
    echo "Line ---> ${line}"
    if [ $line = "header-1" -o $line = "header-2" ]
    then
        first_col=$line
    else
        complete_line=`echo $first_col"|"$line`
        echo "$complete_line" >> out.csv
    fi
done < input.txt
```

Shouldn't the input file be read line by line and then create an appended "complete line"? The thing is the program will treat `header-1` and `header-sub1` as two distinct fields and it will not match the complete header line 1. But I know they are on the same line, so they should be considered as a single line. Or maybe I am missing out on the logic and/or syntax somewhere?

Also is there any way I can use sed or awk to create such a file? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} /^header/ {h=$0; next} {print h, $0}' file
header-1 header-sub1|field1|field2|field3|field4
header-1 header-sub1|field5|field6|field7|field8
header-2|field9|field0|fieldA|fieldB
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{OFS="|"}` set the output field separator as `|`.
- `/^header/ {h=$0; next}` if the line starts with `header`, then store it without printing.
- `{print h, $0}` on the rest of the lines, print the stored header first.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and post the results here.

Comment: +1 though instead of using `header` as regex, you can use `NF` to store the lines where `NF==1` as headers.

Comment: Mmmm that's a good point @jaypal, thanks :) But note that the header is also in the line 4, so `/^header/` is the only pattern I can use to check where the headers are.

Comment: Since you split the lines on `|` it will still consider it as header. But it all depends on OPs data.

Comment: @fedorqui, Thanks a lot for your answer. It works exactly as I was looking for! It saved the day for me, thank you so much.

Comment: Aaaaah sorry, @jaypal I misunderstood your previous comment. I thought you were saying `NR==1`, while now I see you said `NF==1`. That makes a lot of sense, yes. I will leave it like it is, as you said because we don't know how OPs data looks like. Thanks master :)

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry, I didn't see this earlier (was from my phone), but I though you had `FS` in your `begin` hence that suggestion. Though no benefit of stating `OFS` as you are printing entire line.

Comment: @jaypal I also cannot help checking SO from my phone :) Yes, it initially had `FS` set but then I saw it is not necessary. Regarding `OFS`, it is needed in the `print h, $0`. Otherwise it would print a space instead of `|`.

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry you're right. What was I thinking! `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^header/{h;d};G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2|\1/' file
```

Store the `header` in the hold space and inserts it before `non-header` lines.